# font awesome icon in asp.net Label in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, label

I have a label in a gridview, and I want to put an awesome icon font inside the label according to the value of a field, my code is:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("<i class='fa fa-{0}'></i>", Eval("[TypeIconFF]")) %>' EncodeHtml="false" />
```

But it gives me an exception of type System.Web.HttpException (Wrong server label)

I think the error may be generated by single quotation marks

Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
  Text='<%# $@"<i class=""fa fa-{Eval("TypeIconFF")}""></i>"  %>'
 >
</asp:Label>
```

Not sure if you need the [], but then this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
  Text='<%# $@"<i class=""fa fa-{Eval("[TypeIconFF]")}""></i>"  %>'
 >
</asp:Label>
```

you also should not need the html encode option.

So, with this grid:

I also like the fa-lg (larger).

So this gv:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"  CssClass="table table-hover" Width="52%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# $@"<i class=""fa fa-{Eval("FA")} fa-lg""></i>"  %>'>
                </asp:Label>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And code :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = General.MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblhotelsA");
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

and I get/see this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the second set of single quotes around `fa fa-{0}`.

Change them to double quotes and escape them and it will work.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("<i class=\"fa fa-{0}\"></i>", Eval("[TypeIconFF]")) %>' EncodeHtml="false" />
```